# Selecting dropdown values using Select class?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have two doubts:

1. Suppose if in a drop down there are two values with the same name, then how can I select the one value from them using Select class?
2. Suppose in a drop down there is a value "Emergency". I need to run the script in dev and production. In dev url the drop down value is coming in Uppercase i.e EMERGENCY. But in Prod env the drop down value is coming in lowerase i.e Emergency.I need to make the script in such a way that it will select the dropdown value irrespective of the case of the drop down value. I can do it by checking if the env is dev then do this else do this. but i dont want to do like this way. How can i do it using Select class or any other relevant way to do it?

Comment: Can you please explain your 2nd doubt in a better way. It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Are the `values` of the elements different? You could `selectByValue()` instead of `selectByVisibleText()` probably for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

> **Doubt 1:** Suppose if in a drop down there are two values with the same name,
>   then how can I select the one value from them using Select class?

You can go for selectByIndex or selectByValue method. So If you know that out of the two options in the drop-down which are same, and you want to select the 2nd one then select the option by index.

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dropDown_id_here")));
select.selectByIndex(2);
```

If the text of the 2 options is same and the values are different, then you can use:

```
select.selectByValue("op2");
```

> **Doubt 2:** Suppose in a drop down there is a value "Emergency". I need to run the
>   script in dev and production. In dev url the drop down value is coming
>   in Uppercase i.e EMERGENCY. But in Prod env the drop down value is
>   coming in lowerase i.e Emergency.I need to make the script in such a
>   way that it will select the dropdown value irrespective of the case of
>   the drop down value. I can do it by checking if the env is dev then do
>   this else do this. but i dont want to do like this way. How can i do
>   it using Select class or any other relevant way to do it?

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dropDown_id_here")));
List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();

for(WebElement option : options)
 {
   if(option.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("emergency"))
    {
      option.click();
      break;
    }
 }
```

Please note that I have written the above code on the fly in this editor. It **could** be syntactically wrong. Kindly just get the idea out of it.

Comment: select.selectByIndex(2); what is 2 here? 2 is the index of second option that i am looking for....suppose in a drop down there are 20 drop down values and two are of same string/text say Emergency..Emergency may not appear one after another might be appearing in different order..in this case how to handle?

Comment: Out of those two which one do YOU want to select? Is there any specific scenario to your test that makes you want to select a specific 'Emergency' option. If so what makes that option specific? the value of that option? the output of the selection of that option?

Answer (score 0):

you have other options

1. select by value

   selectByValue(value);
2. Select by index

   selectByIndex(index);